# How to use a generic interface?

Tags: typescript, interface

I can't figure out how I can have my props' types linked together

```js
interface MyExample {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

```js
export interface ListItemProps<ItemType> {
    value: keyof ItemType;
    formatter?: <K extends keyof ItemType>(value: ItemType[K]) => ItemType[K];
}

const ListItem = <T extends {}>(props: ListItemProps<T>) => null;

export default ListItem;
```

So when I do

```js
<ListItem<MyExample> value="name" formatter={(val: string) => val.toUpperCase()} />
<ListItem<MyExample> value="id" formatter={(val: number) => String(id)} />
```

It should not warn me about formatter.

Actually I got :
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: [Please include error messages and example code as text, not as an image](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need an extra type parameter to keep the actual type that will represent the key that is being used.

```
interface MyExample {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
export interface ListItemProps<ItemType, K extends keyof ItemType> {
    value: K;
    formatter?: (value: ItemType[K]) => string;
}

const ListItem = <T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(props: ListItemProps<T, K>) => null;


let s = <ListItem<MyExample, "name"> value="name" formatter={(val) => val.toUpperCase()} />
let s2 = <ListItem<MyExample, "id"> value="id" formatter={(val) => val.toFixed(4)} />
```

Ideally, `value` would be inferred from usage but TS does not support partial type inference so this is the best we can do (it will [soon](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349) hopefully but that feature looks like it ewill ont be for JSX tags at least at first)

If we don't mind using HOC, we could also write:

```
interface MyExample {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
export interface ListItemProps<ItemType, K extends keyof ItemType> {
    value: K;
    formatter?: (value: ItemType[K]) => string;
}

const ListItem = <T extends {}>() => <K extends keyof T>(props: ListItemProps<T, K>) => null;

const MyExampleListItem = ListItem<MyExample>();
const s = <MyExampleListItem value="name" formatter={(val) => val.toUpperCase()} />;
const s2 = <MyExampleListItem value="id" formatter={(val) => val.toFixed(4)} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

`(value: ItemType[K]) => ItemType[K]` defines that the input and return value must be the same.

Therefore `formatter={(val: MyExample['name']) => 'coucou'}` is not valid, as input (MyExample[string]) and return (string) are not the same.

So I think you should change `(value: ItemType[K]) => ItemType[K]` to `(value: ItemType[K]) => ItemType[K] | string`